# Is there any API to fetch currency data from NSE website?

Tags: json, api

The below link fetches the stock options quote for derivatives...
https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE
I found this one working, so expected that there should also be the one for currency market segment.

Is there any link that can help me also fetch data for currencies like USDINR, EURINR, GBPINR & JPYINR?
Both for futures and options.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)